# Menus change direction (right to left)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidenav menu that slides onto the screen with hover event.  When the menu opens, I would like for the icons to be on the right side of the text.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/post98/zRQ87/6/embedded/result/)

[**Mouse Leave**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qljlgt26okx97nd/mouseleave.PNG)

[**Mouse Over**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/z58oktje72igjn2/Mouseover.PNG)

CSS Code:

```
.sidenav ul > li a div {
width: 70px;
position: absolute;
left: 0; --> right:0
top: 0;
padding: 14px 24px;
height: 51px; }
```

Comment: can you be more clear what you are looking for?

Comment: when the menu slides open, i want the icons to be on the right side of the text.

Comment: thanks for the edit Chris, really helps!

Comment: this can be done by just having the images themselves not move, and have the menu slide away from them, rather than have the menu replace the images and push them to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could just change the css properties that dictate the position of those element in your mouseover / mouseleave functions like this:

```
$(".sidenav.right").mouseover(function () {
  $('.sidenav ul > li a div').css('left', 'inherit');
  $('.sidenav ul > li a div').css('right', '0');
  $('.sidenav ul > li a').css('paddingLeft', '15px');
  $(".sidenav.right").addClass('sidenavhover');
  $(".sidenav.right li.user").addClass('usershow');
  $(".overlay").fadeIn();
});
$(".sidenav.right").mouseleave(function () {
  $('.sidenav ul > li a div').css('right', 'inherit');
  $('.sidenav ul > li a div').css('left', '0');
  $('.sidenav ul > li a').css('paddingLeft', '100px');
  $(".sidenav.right").removeClass('sidenavhover');
  $(".sidenav.right li.user").removeClass('usershow');
  $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/m6K5z/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zRQ87/7/)**

```
$(".sidenav.right").mouseleave(function () {
      $(".sidenav.right").removeClass('sidenavhover');
      $(".sidenav.right li.user").removeClass('usershow');
      $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

The main component on which mouseover and mouseleave events occurs is`<nav>` with classes sidenav,right.

Comment: This was not what I wanted, 
In fact it was the same theme. 
You can mouse over the icons on the right in the photo above are consistent

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with your english and it is making it difficult for us to understand what you are looking for.  This answer by shaundakde is what I thought you were looking for also.

Comment: ok, I think I figured out what you want.  when the menu slides open, you want the icons to be on the right side of the text.  Is that it?